# Editing the aspectual coercion question

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

[Is there any language that doesn't express Tense but allows “aspectual coercion”?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1022/2555)

This question is quite unclear. I asked the OP if this is what they meant but they never replied. Do you think it is the correct understanding of the question, and should I just go ahead to edit it?

> Are you asking for a language for which neither tense nor aspect are grammaticalised, but which allows adjunct phrases to give aspectual information?

Comment: If they can't be bothered to clarify their question, there's no need for anybody to do it for them. We have enough on our plates as it is. GIGO.